# Converting Java State Machine Example to C++, Stuck on last hurdle

Tags: c++, c++11

#### Background

I'm getting back into C++ after a bit of a hiatus. I never was fantastic at C or C++, but I considered myself to have a bit of a working knowledge.

I set off with a simple goal. Convert a Java state-machine example to C++
I Think the problem is in passing a `new State<CeilingFanPullChain>`, I've added empty stub constructors to the classes that inherit from my template interface (used to get around dependency issue that should probably be solved by altering the design).

As a requirement from myself to myself, I don't want to use pre-processor magic, which is what a lot of online examples seem to use. I also do not want to use a switch statement. I'd like to make this as Object-Oriented as possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// The CeilingFanPullChain class is now a wrapper
// that delegates to its m_current_state reference.
// Each clause from the "before" case statement is
// now captured in a State derived class.

// For this simple domain, the State pattern is
// probably over-kill.


template <class T>
class State {
public:
    virtual void pull( T &wrapper ) = 0;
};

class CeilingFanPullChain {

private:
    State<CeilingFanPullChain>* m_current_state;

public:
    CeilingFanPullChain() {
        m_current_state = new Off();
    }
    void set_state( State<CeilingFanPullChain>* s ) {
        m_current_state = s;
    }
    void pull() {
        m_current_state->pull( *this );
    }
};

class Off: public State<CeilingFanPullChain> {
public:
    Off() {}
    void pull( CeilingFanPullChain &wrapper ) {
        wrapper.set_state( new Low() );
        std::cout << "   low speed\n";
    }
};

class Low: State<CeilingFanPullChain> {
public:
    Low() {}
    void pull( CeilingFanPullChain &wrapper ) {
        wrapper.set_state( new Medium() );
        std::cout << "   medium speed\n";
    }
};

class Medium: State<CeilingFanPullChain> {
public:
    Medium() {}
    void pull( CeilingFanPullChain &wrapper ) {
        wrapper.set_state( new High() );
        std::cout << "   high speed\n";
    }
};

class High: State<CeilingFanPullChain> {
public:
    High() {}
    void pull( CeilingFanPullChain &wrapper ) {
        wrapper.set_state( new Off() );
        std::cout << "   turning off\n";
    }
};

std::string get_line() {
    std::string line_tmp;
    std::getline(std::cin, line_tmp);
    return line_tmp;
}

int main() {
    CeilingFanPullChain* chain = new CeilingFanPullChain();
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Press \n";
        get_line();
        chain->pull();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Error Output

```
ceiling-fan.cpp: In constructor ‘CeilingFanPullChain::CeilingFanPullChain()’:
ceiling-fan.cpp:26:31: error: expected type-specifier before ‘Off’
         m_current_state = new Off();
                               ^
ceiling-fan.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void Off::pull(CeilingFanPullChain&)’:
ceiling-fan.cpp:40:32: error: expected type-specifier before ‘Low’
         wrapper.set_state( new Low() );
                                ^
ceiling-fan.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void Low::pull(CeilingFanPullChain&)’:
ceiling-fan.cpp:49:32: error: expected type-specifier before ‘Medium’
         wrapper.set_state( new Medium() );
                                ^
ceiling-fan.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void Medium::pull(CeilingFanPullChain&)’:
ceiling-fan.cpp:58:32: error: expected type-specifier before ‘High’
         wrapper.set_state( new High() );
```

Comment: You've forgotten that classes need to be defined before use. Drop the Java habit of defining all member functions in the class definitions. You've also forgotten about memory management – all your state changes leak. (You should probably get your old C++ book out from the attic.)

Comment: You've forgotten that C++ doesn't have ref counting by default. `CeilingFanPullChain* chain = new CeilingFanPullChain` needs a corresponding `delete` or it's a leak, or you could use a smart pointer with `auto chain = std::make_unique<CeilingFanPulllChain>()`.

Comment: You said you didn't want to resort to `switch`, but now that you appealed to `std::map`, you are doing a tree search, which seems even more work.  Look Niall's answer below, and apply to your state classes the same idea of splitting declaration and definition as he showed for `CeilingFanPullChain`.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my own problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

// The CeilingFanPullChain class is now a wrapper
// that delegates to its m_current_state reference.
// Each clause from the "before" case statement is
// now captured in a State derived class.

// For this simple domain, the State pattern is
// probably over-kill.


template <class T>
class State {
public:
    virtual void pull( T &wrapper ) = 0;
};

class CeilingFanPullChain {

private:
    std::shared_ptr<State<CeilingFanPullChain>> m_current_state;
    std::map <std::string, std::shared_ptr<State<CeilingFanPullChain> > >& m_states;
public:
    CeilingFanPullChain(std::map <std::string, std::shared_ptr<State<CeilingFanPullChain> > >& states) : m_states(states) {
        m_current_state.reset();
        m_current_state = m_states["Off"];
    }
    void set_state( const std::string new_state) {
        if(m_states.find(new_state) != m_states.end()) {
            m_current_state.reset();
            m_current_state = m_states[new_state];
        }
    }
    void pull() {
        m_current_state->pull( *this );
    }
    ~CeilingFanPullChain() {
    }
};

class Off: public State<CeilingFanPullChain> {
public:
    Off() {}
    void pull( CeilingFanPullChain &wrapper ) {
        wrapper.set_state( "Low" );
        std::cout << "low speed" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Low: public State<CeilingFanPullChain> {
public:
    Low() {}
    void pull( CeilingFanPullChain &wrapper ) {
        wrapper.set_state( "Medium" );
        std::cout << "medium speed" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Medium: public State<CeilingFanPullChain> {
public:
    Medium() {}
    void pull( CeilingFanPullChain &wrapper ) {
        wrapper.set_state( "High" );
        std::cout << "high speed" << std::endl;
    }
};

class High: public State<CeilingFanPullChain> {
public:
    High() {}
    void pull( CeilingFanPullChain &wrapper ) {
        wrapper.set_state( "Off" );
        std::cout << "turning off" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Program {
private:
    std::map <std::string, std::shared_ptr<State<CeilingFanPullChain> > > m_state_list;
    CeilingFanPullChain* m_chain = 0;
public:
    Program() {

        m_state_list["Off"] = std::make_shared<Off>();
        m_state_list["Low"] = std::make_shared<Low>();
        m_state_list["Medium"] = std::make_shared<Medium>();
        m_state_list["High"] = std::make_shared<High>();

        m_chain = new CeilingFanPullChain(m_state_list);
    }

    void run() {
        int i = 0;

        show_help();
        while (true) {
            std::string Input = get_line();

            std::transform(Input.begin(), Input.end(), Input.begin(), tolower);
            if( Input.compare(quit) == 0) {
                std::cout << "Exiting" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
            if( Input.compare(pull) == 0 ) {
                m_chain->pull();
                i++; 
            } else if( Input.compare(help) == 0) {
                show_help();
            } else {
                std::cout << "Sorry, I didn't get that, please make a choice from the options shown" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        if( i > 3 ) { 
            std::cout << "Wow... you changed the fan " << i << " times! Are you okay?" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Bye..." << std::endl;
    }

    ~Program() {
        m_state_list.clear();
        delete m_chain;
    }

    void show_help() {
        std::cout << "Enter a command, and then press <Enter>" << std::endl;
        std::cout << pull << " : pull-chain (next setting)" << std::endl;
        std::cout << quit << " : exit" << std::endl;
        std::cout << help << " : show help" << std::endl;
    }

    std::string get_line() {
        std::string line_tmp;
        std::getline(std::cin, line_tmp);

        return line_tmp;
    }
protected:
    std::string const quit = "q";
    std::string const pull = "p";
    std::string const help = "h";
};

int main() {
    auto p = std::make_unique<Program>();
    p->run();
    return 0;
}
```

I used the `std::map` so that I was not creating a `CeilingFanPullChain` that knew all of it's states (or created them); and instead relied on the states being type-compatible with my template class.

I've also made the main program into it's own class; so that I can go through, find and clear up memory leaks (of which I am sure there are a few, and would be happy to have them pointed out).

I'm only a little disappointed at myself that I probably won't use this at all now that it compiles. For one thing the state machine runs indefinitely. The infinite while loop should run until some pre-determined condition is set.

#### To compile on a linux machine I use

`g++ -std=gnu++14 -Wall -pedantic ceiling-fan.cpp -o ceiling-fan`

#### What I like about this solution

- It compiles (always nice)
- It reads quite easily from top->bottom
- It does not directly use pre-processors, or inline class definitions

#### What could be improved

- Garbage Collection
- Usefulness of example code
- Separation of code
- *Open to more suggestions on this*

Comment: You have an implicit leak of "Program". Why not just use `Program p; p.run()` so that the object can be cleaned up at the end of scope automatically. Otherwise, `auto p = std::make_unique<Program>();`.

Comment: Surely an explicit delete would work? AFAIK you cannot run `std::make_unique` with non-scalar types

Comment: The states allocated by `new` aren't deleted either. (only the lists holding them are cleared)

Comment: Decided this AM to finalize the code, clean up bits I didn't like. I'm quite happy with it.